# Gui JFrame wil not size to the size that is need from the JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface, frame

The problem that i have is that my frame will not resizes to the size that is needed from the frame. I am using pack() to do this.

I first looked if there was any code missing but i couldn't find any. After that i checked of the code order had something to do with it but it doens't solve the problem.

PS hopefully it is not a to stupid question but i expected that i have overseen something.

Here is my code:
The **Main** class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();

MyContentPane myContentPane = new MyContentPane();      

myFrame.add(myContentPane);

myContentPane.create();

}
```

The **Frame** class

```
public MyFrame() {


this.setTitle("PROG3 week4B simpel-anders");

this.pack();

this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

this.setVisible(true);

}
```

The **Panel** class

```
public class MyContentPane extends JPanel {

public void create() {

this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
g.setColor(Color.RED);

g.fillRect(0,0,300,300);

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `pack()` method after you call `create()` method of your content pane.

Comment: Thank you this was quite a bad question